# Is there a word for people who emit positive vibes and negative vibes?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, single-word-requests, word-usage, vocabulary

It's happened to me tons of times. See some people on Tv, live in office or anywhere, meet them and without their saying much you feel some positive energy oozing out of them. Although sometimes it is negative too. When it is -ve you don't like seeing them again.

I was wondering if there is a word for such people ?
Thank you.

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Are you talking about the same person?

Comment: Yes, the very same person. @VeronicaDiamond.

Comment: I don't suppose there is a word for such a person. In fact , I believe everyone has times when he/she gives out positive/negative vibes.

Comment: @VeronicaDiamond, No, some people are neutral. Some are like not creating any image on your mind.

Comment: Well, I will call them 'Moody'.

Comment: Everyone has this *aura* about them, to a smaller or greater extent and it may influence to a smaller or greater extent. In some studies, those with significant influence on others are referred to as the **Influential Type** among 'DISC' group of personality types. https://www.discinsights.com/personality-style-i#.U74wmPuqCho

Comment: Not sure if this Q. fits in on ELU or better asked elsewhere.

Comment: Surely such a person is 'vibrating' ?  Switching polarity yes, but always vibrating.

Answer (score 1):

I might say that the person has an 'infectious personality'. This means that their mood and mannerisms rub off on the people around them.

Answer (score 0):

"Capricious" or "Moody" or "Whimsical"  I guess !

Comment: Your answer would benefit from an explanation as to why you think these words are suitable, with links to dictionaries or examples as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

In the most literal sense, I'd say "Attractive" and "Repulsive" fit nicely here, though I don't think there is a noun form of either that specifically describes a person. "Charismatic" maybe, but that has more a religious connotation.

Answer (score -1):

I don't believe this word exists but this should be exactly what you mean: **Ambitive**.

Consider: 
Extroverted
Introverted
Ambiverted

Which ODE Deluxe defines as

> ► noun
>   Psychology a person who has a balance of extrovert and introvert features in their personality.

It's not neither extroverted nor introverted but like the definition said, a "balance of extrovert and introvert features."

Likewise we have 
Positive
Negative
Ambitive

In theory this would be something having a balance of both positive and negative features.

Unfortunately it seems that this word is nonexistent.